# Checking memory leaks on HPUX

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, hp-ux

What fields of getrusage do I use in order to check for memory leak on HPUX (what is the parallel to RES in 'top')?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with HPUX, but I would suggest compiling your programs on Linux. You can use valgrind, [mtrace](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Allocation-Debugging.html#Allocation-Debugging) or possibly other tools to find memory leaks. Once a memory leak occurs, it always occurs, no matter what OS you are using. Just use an OS with a more complete tool set.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of /proc and others on Linux, but I need to do it programatically on HPUX.

Comment: Sorry, I could not help more. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run top in batch mode?  If you have a leak you should see VIRT and RES going up over time.

```
top -b | grep yourProgram
```

This isn't going to help you find the leak(s) if you have them but its easier than messing with getrusage, which won't be any more help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at `ru_maxrss`. It gives you the resident set size in kilobytes.

```
struct rusage {
    :
    long   ru_maxrss;        /* maximum resident set size */
    :
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the space after `UNIX95=` i.e.

```
UNIX95= ps -e -o "user,vsz,pid,ppid,args" | sort -rnk2 | head
```